How Can I Use Docker's BuildKit to Run a Health Monitoring Script at Container Startup with Conditional Logic?
I’m interested in using Docker's BuildKit to run a health monitoring script at container startup, but I need the script to include conditional logic based on runtime parameters or environment variables. Specifically:
Conditional Logic: How can I structure a health monitoring script that runs during the container startup process to execute different actions based on runtime conditions or environment variables?
Integrating with BuildKit: What are the best practices for integrating such a script into a Docker image using BuildKit?
Examples and Tools: Are there any tools or methods for dynamically configuring the script at build time or runtime to handle different health-related scenarios?
Any insights on combining Docker's BuildKit features with dynamic script execution for health monitoring purposes would be highly valuable!
I tried using Docker’s BuildKit for running a health monitoring script with conditional logic at container startup, expecting guidance on integrating this into the Docker build process dynamically.
